# Where are my personal files saved in C: drive?

Tags: windows

I am trying to free up space from a hard disk I pulled from an old dead laptop, to use as an external storage device.

I am trying to salvage all user data before formatting C: drive. Will any user files be stored in any location outside of the "Users" directory?

Comment: Yes. Maybe. It’s impossible to answer.

Comment: Your files are where you put them.   Documents in USERS is a popular choice.

Comment: User-generated files can certainly be stored outside of the "Users" directory. But whether this occurred would depend on the user and the program (though the majority of these files would still likely be in "Users"). If you're being thorough, you'll probably want to go through the majority of the hard drive manually (skipping obvious exceptions like "Windows", since typically only Windows is allowed to have files there).

Answer (score 0):

To save the data of all users you could backup:

C:\users

To save the data of a specific user you could backup:

c:\Users\username

Usually there's where all the user data is stored, there might be exceptions like if one of the uses changed the location of his files pointing it to another drive. But usually c:\users\username is where all the folders with userstuff are stored like Documents, Videos, Music, Downloads etc.